# await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => versus Task.Start; await Task;

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

Is there any functional difference between these two forms of using await?

1. ```
   string x = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetAnimal("feline"));
   ```
2. ```
   Task<string> myTask = new Task<string>(() => GetAnimal("feline"));
   myTask.Start();
   string z = await myTask;
   ```

Specifically, in what order is each operation called in 1.? Is StartNew called and then is await called, or is await called first in 1.?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`StartNew` is just a [short hand for creating and starting a task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx). If you want to do something to the `Task` instance before you start it, use the constructor. If you just want to create and start the task immediately, use the short hand.

Documentation for `StartNew` says:

> Calling StartNew is functionally equivalent to creating a task by
>   using one of its constructors, and then calling the Task.Start method
>   to schedule the task for execution.

Comment: Upon calling myTask.Start(), GetAnimal("feline") is called immediately, which makes sense because I started the Task. Does this mean I can start numerous Tasks immediately and then later decide when I want to call await for each Task?

Comment: @user42: of course. (But I wouldn't say that calling in another thread is completely "immediate".)

Answer (score 33):

When you're writing code with `async` and `await`, you should use `Task.Run` whenever possible.

The `Task` constructor (and `Task.Start`) are holdovers from the Task Parallel Library, used to create tasks that have not yet been started. The `Task` constructor and `Task.Start` should not be used in `async` code.

Similarly, `TaskFactory.StartNew` is an older method that does not use the best defaults for `async` tasks and does not understand `async` lambdas. It can be useful in a few situations, but the vast majority of the time `Task.Run` is better for `async` code.

Comment: is this the better way? ... `delegate string AnimalDelegate(string t);` `AnimalDelegate a = new AnimalDelegate(GetAnimal);` `var result = await Task.Run(() => { return a("feline"); });`

Comment: You could just say `var result = await Task.Run(() => GetAnimal("feline"));`