# Task await confusion

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have the following

```
async void A () {
  await B();
}

async Task B () {
  await Task.Factory.StratNew( ()=> C());
}

async Task C () {
  while (true) {
    //await Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> {Thread.Sleep(5000);});
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
  }
}
```

In the program above, `A` never returns because the while loop inside `C`. However if I uncomment the line inside `C` and KEEP `Thread.Sleep(5000)`, `A` immediately returns. Could someone explain what is happening in there ?

Comment: When you uncomment the line you also comment out the Thread.Sleep(5000); right?

Comment: @rbaghbanli no I don't

Comment: [StartNew is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), you could end up running code on the UI thread when you don't expect it to, use Task.Run instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is thorouhly described in the article [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx). If you were to change your code like this you would see what you were expecting I think.

```
async void A()
{
    await B(); 
}

async Task B()
{
    // await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => C());
    await Task.Run(async () => await C());
    // await Task.Run(() => C()); // this would still produce the same effect
}

async Task C()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        //Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

See also this [previous answer by Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17001651/1260204). Essentially `Task.Factory.StartNew` does not respect the `async/await` model and you really should be using `Task.Run` with `async/await` code. `Task.Factory.StartNew` creates and starts a new Task without acually awaiting the results with the exception of when the Task returned is executed synchronously which happened when you removed the await inside of `C`.

Comment: with the line `commented` A never returns, with the line `uncommented` A returns immediately. I think your explanation means the opposite.

Comment: @MonsterHunter - thanks for that! I delved a little deeper into the problem and the answer has to do with `Task.Factory.StartNew` and how it should not be used for `async/await` because it is a TPL library initially developed for parallelism and not for the `async/await` framework which was created later.

Answer (score 2):

When you have "await" inside you infinite loop, runtime interrupts infinite loop, yielding execution to outer calls, giving the chance to complete B (and consequently A) then it returns back to infinite loop.

Without the "await" there is no way B (and consequently A) can ever finish, they will "await" forever.

Comment: Then with the uncommented line, `B` should still pause for 5 seconds because the `Thread.Sleep(5000)` inside the most inner await, right ? But instead `A` just returned immediately.

Comment: Wrong. Async call returns back all the way to A because all calls are async. So, essentially A completes before it starts waiting for 5 secs :)

Comment: I guess my confusion is that `await` ensures that `A` doesn't return until `B` is done. `B` doesn't return until thread running `C` is completed. `C` never returns, the `await` inside just yield the process. What's wrong with my logic ?

Comment: @MonsterHunter The thing that is wrong with your logic is A, B and C all return immedatly as soon as it hits the first `await` with a task that repesents the rest of the code that will go to the `Completed` state when done. Because your first `C` had no `await` in it, it never returned. And because C never returns, B never got to it's await, and because B never got to it's await it never returned either. You should have gotten a compiler warning about C that it was a async method with no await instead of it.