# Don't return from action until task ends

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am a little bit lost in async tasks within `ASP.NET Web API` action. I have an action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Restart()
{
    await AspManager.Restart();

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { result = "Success", message = "IIS site successfully restarted" });
}
```

Restart may be long running and I want to wait for it and then return a response. Here is the long running code:

```
public static async Task<Task> Restart()
{
    var client = new Client("...");
    CheckApiKey(client);

    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        client.Stop();

        await Task.Delay(5 * 1000);

        throw new BusinessException("test");
        client.Start();
    });

    return await task;
}
```

So in main `Restart` method I am checking a key, then I should stop a service, wait 5 seconds and start a service. Action from the controller should not return until this work is done. But the problem is that action returns and after 5 seconds `BusinessException` is thrown.

Comment: You are throwing a new exception in your Task. Why do you expect anything else?

Comment: Hmmm, that throw is for testing. The problem as I described is that I need to wait till client stops and starts and then return http response. But here it first returns and only then exception is thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is an `async Task<Task>`, and you're starting a task and returning that. This means you're returning a task has just started.

Key point being: you're awaiting the task creation, not its execution.

Change your method signature to be an "async void", then, from [await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => versus Task.Start; await Task;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001448/await-task-factory-startnew-versus-task-start-await-task), use `Task.Run()`:

```
public async Task Restart()
{
    // ...

    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        client.Stop();

        await Task.Delay(5 * 1000);

        client.Start();
    });
}
```

Comment: You are my hero today :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[`Task.Factory.StartNew` is a dangerous API](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), as I explain on my blog. The problem you're running into is that it doesn't understand `async` lambdas. (There are other problems, too).

However, using `Task.Run` is not an appropriate solution. It's counterproductive on ASP.NET. You should just use `await` by itself:

```
public static async Task<Task> RestartAsync()
{
  var client = new Client("...");
  if (CheckApiKey(client))
    return;

  client.Stop();
  await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
  client.Start();
}
```